# How to record when a state changes in Workflow Gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, workflow, state-machine

I'm using the Workflow gem (https://github.com/geekq/workflow) in my Rails App as a state machine.  As an object passes through various states, I'd like to record the datetime when it changes, but not too sure if that's so straightforward.

One approach I may take is one extra column called 'workflow_state_date_changed', and update this column whenever the state changes - this was I could see how long the object has been in a particular state.  What it won't allow, however, is to historically look at all the states it past through, and the time spent in each.  Any thoughts of a way of achieving this in a fairly light way?

Look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a solution from scratch, following Ryan Bate's excellent screencast at:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/392-a-tour-of-state-machines?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Observer](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/19-use-observer) to record events on attributes. If you use [StateMachine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) it supports observation on different methods like `after_transition`. I don't know how `Observer` can be used with `workflow`

Answer (score 0):

use state_machine gem  it very powerful and you can do it very easy

https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Comment: I actually ended up writing my own functions.  Originally I was put off state_machine as it's over 3,000 lines of code and I try to be mindful of using big gems when I only end up using them once or twice.

Comment: :) good but always it's depend of your state machine and the complexity of transitions between events,